# Excel 2010 - Calculated metrics in Pivot-tables using subsets of data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

A column `(sentiment)` in my dataset can have following values:

`["positive", "negative"]`

I want to create a new `pivot-table` with a `calculated metric` which shows an index obtained with the following logic:

`sum[sentiment="positive"]-sum[sentiment="negative"]/count[sentiment]`

It's possible to achieve this within a calculated metric?

`

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the pivot table, add a column to your spreadsheet called something like "metric", create your formula using countif() to count instances of "positive" and "negative", in the "metric" column.  With that done, create your pivot table.